# Only the last client is getting data sent

Tags: java, tcp, server, client, multiplayer

I have a small problem. I am new to multiplayer programming. My problem is that one packet that gets sent only gets sent to the last client. It can support 2 players easily, but 3 players doesn't fully work. The login and disconnect packets work, but not the move packet. Can you tell me what I'm missing or need to remove?

Client:

```
public class Client extends Thread{
private InetAddress ip;
private DatagramSocket dp;

public Client(String ia) {
    try {
    dp = new DatagramSocket();
    ip = InetAddress.getByName(ia);
    } catch (SocketException | UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        byte[] rdata = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket dg = new DatagramPacket(rdata, rdata.length);
        try {
            dp.receive(dg);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] data = dg.getData();
        String msg = new String(data).trim();
        switch (Packet.find(msg.substring(0, 2))) {
            default:
            case INVALID:
                break;
            case LOGIN:
                Login00 l = new Login00(data);
                if (getPlayer(l.getUser()) == null) {
                Main.visible.add(new MPlayer(100, 100, l.getUser(), dg.getAddress(), dg.getPort(), false));
                System.out.println("("+dg.getAddress().getHostAddress()+":"+dg.getPort()+") > " + msg.substring(2) + " has joined!");
                }
                break;
            case DISCONNECT:
                Dis01 d = new Dis01(data);
                Main.visible.remove(getPlayer(d.getUser()));
     System.out.println(("+dg.getAddress().getHostAddress()+":"+dg.getPort()+") > " + d.getUser() + " has left!");
                break;
            case MOVE:
                Move02 m = new Move02(data);
                handleMove(m);
                break;
        }
    }
}

public void sendData(byte[] data) {
    try {
    DatagramPacket dg = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ip, 1111);
    dp.send(dg);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public MPlayer getPlayer(String u) {
    for (Player p : Main.visible) {
        if (p.user.equals(u)) {
            return (MPlayer) p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public int getPlayerId(String u) {
    int dex = 0;
    for (Player p : Main.visible) {
        if (p.user.equals(u)) {
            break;
        }
        dex++;
    }
    return dex;
}

private void handleMove(Move02 m) {
    int dex = getPlayerId(m.getUser());
    Main.visible.get(dex).moveTo(m.getX(), m.getY(), m.getUser());
}
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server extends Thread{
private DatagramSocket dp;
List<MPlayer> cplayers = new ArrayList<>();

public Server() {
    try {
    dp = new DatagramSocket(1111);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        byte[] rdata = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket dg = new DatagramPacket(rdata, rdata.length);
        try {
            dp.receive(dg);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        pp(dg.getData(), dg.getAddress(), dg.getPort());
    }
}

public void sendData(byte[] data, InetAddress i, int port) {
    try {
        DatagramPacket dg = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, i, port);
        dp.send(dg);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}

public void sendDataAll(byte[] data) {
    for (MPlayer p : cplayers) {
        sendData(data, p.ip, p.port);
    }
}

private void pp(byte[] data, InetAddress address, int port) {
    String msg = new String(data).trim();
    types t = Packet.find(Integer.parseInt(msg.substring(0, 2)));
    Packet pp;
    switch (t) {
        default:
        case INVALID:
            break;
        case LOGIN:
            pp = new Login00(data);
            System.out.println("("+address.getHostAddress()+":"+port+") > " + ((Login00) pp).getUser() + " has joined!");
            MPlayer pl = new MPlayer(100, 100, ((Login00) pp).getUser(), address, port, false);
            addPlayer(pl, (Login00) pp);
            break;
        case DISCONNECT:
            pp = new Dis01(data);
            System.out.println("("+address.getHostAddress()+":"+port+") > " + ((Dis01) pp).getUser() + " has left!");
            removePlayer((Dis01) pp);
            break;
        case MOVE:
            pp = new Move02(data);
            handleMove((Move02) pp);
            break;
    }
}

public void addPlayer(MPlayer pl, Login00 l) {
    boolean ac = false;
    for (MPlayer p : cplayers) {
        p.ip = pl.ip;
        p.port = pl.port;
        if (Main.username.equalsIgnoreCase(l.getUser())) {
            ac = true;
        } else {
            sendDataAll(l.getData());
            Login00 ll = new Login00(p.user);
            sendData(ll.getData(), p.ip, p.port);
        }
    }
    if (true) {
        cplayers.add(pl);
        Main.visible.add(pl);
    } 

}

public void removePlayer(Dis01 dis) {
    Main.visible.remove(getPlayer(dis.getUser()));
    cplayers.remove(getPlayer(dis.getUser()));
    dis.write(this);
}

public MPlayer getPlayer(String u) {
    for (MPlayer p : cplayers) {
        if (p.user.equals(u)) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public int getPlayerId(String u) {
    int dex = 0;
    for (Player p : Main.visible) {
        if (p.user.equals(u)) {
            break;
        }
        dex++;
    }
    return dex;
}

public void handleMove(Move02 m) {
        Integer dex = getPlayerId(m.getUser());
        Main.visible.get(dex).moveTo(m.getX(), m.getY(), m.getUser());
        m.write(this);
}
}
```

**EDIT:** So I figured out that i need to change the addPlayer method in the Server class to:

```
public void addPlayer(MPlayer pl, Login00 l) {
    cplayers.add(pl);
    Main.visible.add(pl);
    for (MPlayer p : cplayers) {
        sendDataAll(l.getData());
        Login00 ll = new Login00(p.user);
        sendDataAll(ll.getData());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a player, you overwrite all existing player ip's and port's

```
// Server code
public void addPlayer(MPlayer pl, Login00 l) {
    boolean ac = false;
    for (MPlayer p : cplayers) {
        // At this point, you overwrite all existing player data
        p.ip = pl.ip; // overwrites existing player
        p.port = pl.port; // overwrites existing player
        if (Main.username.equalsIgnoreCase(l.getUser())) {
            ac = true;
        } else {
            sendDataAll(l.getData());
            Login00 ll = new Login00(p.user);
            sendData(ll.getData(), p.ip, p.port);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so should i remove that?

Comment: @TheKindOfGoodProgrammer Yes, but only the overwrite parts. Why you did that?

Comment: when i do that, the second client doesn't get any players

Comment: @TheKindOfGoodProgrammer you first need to add the new player to the  arraylist and **then** call the for loop

Comment: when i do that, it has 4 players in #1, 2 players in #2, and 1 player in #3

Comment: Ok, good news, the 2nd client is reading corrrectly, but the clients don't read the clients before them.

Comment: @TheKindOfGoodProgrammer I can't go deeper into your code but you need to learn how to debug your application so you can investigate the problems step by step. If you are using eclipse, this might be helpfull: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: i figured it out! I needed to change `Login00 ll = new Login00(p.user);
            sendData(ll.getData(), p.ip, p.port);` to 'Login00 ll = new Login00(p.user);
            sendDataAll(ll.getData());'